I cannot communicate with Android HCE with another Android Device in reader mode
I'm developing an app in Flutter to clock in and clock out from work with only tablet ora smartphones, for privacy and security reasons i need to use NFC and not Bluetooth or Wifi.
I decided to emulate a badge on Android device and so i will use another Iphone or Android Phone to read that badge.
Using the Flutter_nfc_kit I'm able to send a custom byte array with some info from my reader to my HCE badge on the Android phone, but this solution works only when I use an iphone as reader(iphone 15), otherwise if i use the reader app on my Android phone (s21) in the HCE app this custom byte never come.
I'm trying to workaround this problem using also native code on Android side, but using NfcAdapter in reader mode and transceive command the result is always the same.
Anyone has a valid solution or have an idea on waht's appening?
This is the code in flutter that work on ios but fail on android:
(the transceive command return [111, 0] as result on android, on IOS the result is [144, 0].
void startNFCScanning(String data) async{
  await FlutterNfcKit.finish();
  var availability = await FlutterNfcKit.nfcAvailability;
  if (availability != NFCAvailability.available) {
    // oh-no
  }

// timeout only works on Android, while the latter two messages are only for iOS

  var tag = await FlutterNfcKit.poll(
      iosMultipleTagMessage: "Multiple tags found!",androidCheckNDEF: true, iosAlertMessage: "Scan your tag", readIso14443A: true, readIso14443B: false, readIso15693: false, readIso18092: false);
  print(jsonEncode(tag));

//https://gist.github.com/hemantvallabh/d24d71a933e7319727cd3daa50ad9f2c
  //SEND DATA
  final pswApdu = commandSignaturePin("ciao".codeUnits);
  final ss = Uint8List.fromList(pswApdu);
  var result = FlutterNfcKit.transceive(ss, timeout: Duration(seconds: 20)).then((value){
    final e = value;

  }).catchError((error){
    final i = error;
    return null;
  });// time)out is still Android-only, persist until next change
  print(await result);

// iOS only: set alert message on-the-fly
// this will persist until finish()
  await FlutterNfcKit.setIosAlertMessage("hi there!");


// read NDEF records if available
  if (tag.ndefAvailable == true) {
    /// decoded NDEF records (see [ndef.NDEFRecord] for details)
    /// `UriRecord: id=(empty) typeNameFormat=TypeNameFormat.nfcWellKnown type=U uri=https://github.com/nfcim/ndef`

    String value = "";

    String rowValue = "";
    for (var record in await FlutterNfcKit.readNDEFRecords(cached: false)) {
      if(record is TextRecord && record.text != null){
        value = record.text!;
        print(record.toString());
      }
    }
    /// raw NDEF records (data in hex string)
    /// `{identifier: "", payload: "00010203", type: "0001", typeNameFormat: "nfcWellKnown"}`
    /*for (var record in await FlutterNfcKit.readNDEFRawRecords(cached: false)) {
        rowValue = jsonEncode(record).toString();
        print(jsonEncode(record).toString());
      }

       */
  }

// Call finish() only once
  await FlutterNfcKit.finish();
// iOS only: show alert/error message on finish
  await FlutterNfcKit.finish(iosAlertMessage: "Success");
// or
  await FlutterNfcKit.finish(iosErrorMessage: "Failed");
}

List<int> commandSignaturePin(List<int> data) {
  var result = <int>[];
  result.addAll(commandPinVerify);
  result.add(data.length.toUnsigned(16));
  result.addAll(data);
  return result;
}
final commandPinVerify = [0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x80];

This is my hce apdu service
package services;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.cardemulation.HostApduService;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;


public class MyHostApduService extends HostApduService {

    // source: https://github.com/TechBooster/C85-Android-4.4-Sample/blob/master/chapter08/NdefCard/src/com/example/ndefcard/NdefHostApduService.java
    
    private final static String TAG = "MyHostApduService";

    private static final byte[] SELECT_APPLICATION = {
            (byte) 0x00, // CLA - Class - Class of instruction
            (byte) 0xA4, // INS - Instruction - Instruction code
            (byte) 0x04, // P1  - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
            (byte) 0x00, // P2  - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
            (byte) 0x07, // Lc field    - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
            (byte) 0xD2, (byte) 0x76, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01, // NDEF Tag Application name D2 76 00 00 85 01 01
            (byte) 0x00  // Le field    - Maximum number of bytes expected in the data field of the response to the command
    };

    private static final byte[] SELECT_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER = {
            (byte) 0x00, // CLA - Class - Class of instruction
            (byte) 0xa4, // INS - Instruction - Instruction code
            (byte) 0x00, // P1  - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
            (byte) 0x0c, // P2  - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
            (byte) 0x02, // Lc field    - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
            (byte) 0xe1, (byte) 0x03 // file identifier of the CC file
    };

    private static final byte[] SELECT_NDEF_FILE = {
            (byte) 0x00, // CLA - Class - Class of instruction
            (byte) 0xa4, // Instruction byte (INS) for Select command
            (byte) 0x00, // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
            (byte) 0x0c, // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
            (byte) 0x02, // Lc field    - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
            (byte) 0xE1, (byte) 0x04 // file identifier of the NDEF file retrieved from the CC file
    };

    private static final byte[] SELECT_PSW = {
            (byte) 0x00, // CLA - Class - Class of instruction
            (byte) 0x20, // Instruction byte (INS) for Select command
            (byte) 0x00, // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
            (byte) 0x80, // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
    };

    private final static byte[] CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_FILE = new byte[] {
            0x00, 0x0f, // CCLEN
            0x20, // Mapping Version
            0x00, 0x3b, // Maximum R-APDU data size
            0x00, 0x34, // Maximum C-APDU data size
            0x04, 0x06, // Tag & Length
            (byte)0xe1, 0x04, // NDEF File Identifier
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xff, // Maximum NDEF size, do NOT extend this value
            0x00, // NDEF file read access granted
            (byte)0x00, // NDEF File write access denied
    };

    // Status Word success
    private final static byte[] SUCCESS_SW = new byte[] {
            (byte)0x90,
            (byte)0x00,
    };
    // Status Word failure
    private final static byte[] FAILURE_SW = new byte[] {
            (byte)0x6a,
            (byte)0x82,
    };

    private byte[] mNdefRecordFile;

    private boolean mAppSelected; // true when SELECT_APPLICATION detected

    private boolean mCcSelected; // true when SELECT_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER detected

    private boolean mNdefSelected; // true when SELECT_NDEF_FILE detected

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mAppSelected = false;
        mCcSelected = false;
        mNdefSelected = false;

        // default NDEF-message
        final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Messaggio fisso se app chiusa o nessun valore impostato";
        NdefMessage ndefDefaultMessage = getNdefMessage(DEFAULT_MESSAGE);
        // the maximum length is 246 so do not extend this value
        int nlen = ndefDefaultMessage.getByteArrayLength();
        mNdefRecordFile = new byte[nlen + 2];
        mNdefRecordFile[0] = (byte)((nlen & 0xff00) / 256);
        mNdefRecordFile[1] = (byte)(nlen & 0xff);
        System.arraycopy(ndefDefaultMessage.toByteArray(), 0, mNdefRecordFile, 2, ndefDefaultMessage.getByteArrayLength());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            // intent contains a text message
            if (intent.hasExtra("ndefMessage")) {
                NdefMessage ndefMessage = getNdefMessage(intent.getStringExtra("ndefMessage"));
                if (ndefMessage != null) {
                    int nlen = ndefMessage.getByteArrayLength();
                    mNdefRecordFile = new byte[nlen + 2];
                    mNdefRecordFile[0] = (byte) ((nlen & 0xff00) / 256);
                    mNdefRecordFile[1] = (byte) (nlen & 0xff);
                    System.arraycopy(ndefMessage.toByteArray(), 0, mNdefRecordFile, 2, ndefMessage.getByteArrayLength());
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private NdefMessage getNdefMessage(String ndefData) {
        if (ndefData.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        NdefRecord ndefRecord;
        ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createTextRecord("en", ndefData);
        return new NdefMessage(ndefRecord);
    }

    private NdefMessage getNdefUrlMessage(String ndefData) {
        if (ndefData.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        NdefRecord ndefRecord;
        ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(ndefData);
        return new NdefMessage(ndefRecord);
    }

    String datiRicevuti = "";
    /**
     * emulates an NFC Forum Tag Type 4
     */
    @Override
    public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
        String cm = bytesToHex(commandApdu);
        Log.d((TAG), "commandApdu: " + cm);
        byte[] prefix = new byte[4];
        System.arraycopy(commandApdu, 0, prefix, 0, 4);
        //if (Arrays.equals(SELECT_APP, commandApdu)) {
        // check if commandApdu qualifies for SELECT_APPLICATION
        if (Arrays.equals(SELECT_APPLICATION, commandApdu)) {
            mAppSelected = true;
            mCcSelected = false;
            mNdefSelected = false;
            Log.d((TAG), "responseApdu: " + bytesToHex(SUCCESS_SW));
            return SUCCESS_SW;
            // check if commandApdu qualifies for SELECT_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER
        } else if (mAppSelected && Arrays.equals(SELECT_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER, commandApdu)) {
            mCcSelected = true;
            mNdefSelected = false;
            Log.d((TAG), "responseApdu: " + bytesToHex(SUCCESS_SW));
            return SUCCESS_SW;
            // check if commandApdu qualifies for SELECT_NDEF_FILE
        } else if (mAppSelected && Arrays.equals(SELECT_NDEF_FILE, commandApdu)) {
            // NDEF
            mCcSelected = false;
            mNdefSelected = true;
            Log.d((TAG), "responseApdu: " + bytesToHex(SUCCESS_SW));
            return SUCCESS_SW;
            // check if commandApdu qualifies for // READ_BINARY
        }
        else if (mAppSelected && Arrays.equals(SELECT_PSW, prefix)){
            byte lenght = commandApdu[4];
            byte[] psw = new byte[lenght];
            System.arraycopy(commandApdu, 5, psw, 0, lenght);
            datiRicevuti = new String(psw, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            //MyChannel.channel.invokeMethod("nfc_invio_lettura", datiRicevuti);
            return SUCCESS_SW;
        }
        else if (commandApdu[0] == (byte)0x00 && commandApdu[1] == (byte)0xb0) {
            // READ_BINARY
            // get the offset an le (length) data
            //System.out.println("** " + Utils.bytesToHex(commandApdu) + " in else if (commandApdu[0] == (byte)0x00 && commandApdu[1] == (byte)0xb0) {");
            int offset = (0x00ff & commandApdu[2]) * 256 + (0x00ff & commandApdu[3]);
            int le = 0x00ff & commandApdu[4];

            byte[] responseApdu = new byte[le + SUCCESS_SW.length];

            if (mCcSelected && offset == 0 && le == CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_FILE.length) {
                System.arraycopy(CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_FILE, offset, responseApdu, 0, le);
                System.arraycopy(SUCCESS_SW, 0, responseApdu, le, SUCCESS_SW.length);
                String tmp = bytesToHex(responseApdu);
                Log.d((TAG), "responseApdu: " + bytesToHex(responseApdu));
                return responseApdu;
            } else if (mNdefSelected) {
                if (offset + le <= mNdefRecordFile.length) {
                    System.arraycopy(mNdefRecordFile, offset, responseApdu, 0, le);
                    System.arraycopy(SUCCESS_SW, 0, responseApdu, le, SUCCESS_SW.length);
                    Log.d((TAG), "responseApdu: " + bytesToHex(responseApdu));
                    return responseApdu;
                }
            }
        }

        // The tag should return different errors for different reasons
        // this emulation just returns the general error message
        Log.d((TAG), "responseApdu: " + bytesToHex(FAILURE_SW));
        return FAILURE_SW;
    }

    
/*
complete sequence:
commandApdu: 00a4040007d276000085010100
responseApdu: 9000
commandApdu: 00a4000c02e103
responseApdu: 9000
commandApdu: 00b000000f
responseApdu: 000f20003b00340406e10400ff00ff9000
commandApdu: 00a4000c02e104
responseApdu: 9000
commandApdu: 00b0000002
responseApdu: 002e9000
commandApdu: 00b000022e
responseApdu: d1012a55046769746875622e636f6d2f416e64726f696443727970746f3f7461623d7265706f7369746f726965739000    
 */

    /**
     * onDeactivated is called when reading ends
     * reset the status boolean values
     */
    @Override
    public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
        mAppSelected = false;
        mCcSelected = false;
        mNdefSelected = false;
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes)
            result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
}




And this is my xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/servicedesc"
    android:requireDeviceUnlock="true">
    <aid-group android:description="@string/aiddescription"
        android:category="other">
        <!-- Sample for the demo application -->
        <aid-filter android:name="D2760000850101" />
    </aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>
    <!-- ?>D2760000850101-->

I tried to write the Nfc reader part on Android in native code in 2 ways:

Sending in the first transceive the select aid command (00 a4 04 00 07 d2 76 00 00 85 01 01 00) and after my custom command
Sending directly my custom command

The result is always that in my HCE application the selection commands arrives but not my custom byte.

After some tests and research, I'm now able to select my AID and communicate with my HCE service by NFC with another Android device.
As I wrote before, I was coding originally in Flutter and invoking through channels a Kotlin activity to start the NFC Reader and HCE services. I don't know why, but it seems that in my case, the NFC Router wasn't routing well my APDU to my HCE, and starting the HCE and the NFC Reader services from a native Java Activity solved my problems.
I also had to change AID from D2760000850101 (NDEF technology) to F0394148148100.
Now I'm able to communicate with NFC through two Android devices.
I'll attach two github repo with two app samples that helped me to understand where my problem was.
Sender App (HCE)
Reader App (NFC READER)

As a reference there is also https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid as an example of Android NFC HCE implementation and Android Reader app that works Android to Android
